# Microservice and anti-pattern

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, microservices, domain-model

I am doing a microservice and I was trying to make a decision about how to handle Domain Model.
I am planning to have multiple microservices, as an example: A ClientsMS and a PaymentMS. They both need to have a client class. One way is to have client class in both MS and do a mapping between the two, Or have a Model(domain) Microservice which will have client and other classes, and this will be consumed via DLL.
I am not sure f by using DLL I am introducing an anti pattern. but also using Domain model in every MS I will be loosing the SRP and DRY.

Comment: Some might say that microservices are an anti-pattern in and of itself but maybe that's just me being a sourpuss

Comment: @Newtopian Interesting point!

Comment: I realise I probably should have expanded a bit more, that was not very constructive...  I'm not convinced yet that microservice architectures would fit the anti-pattern just yet, I still think that they have their place but there is a hidden cost to them that is often overlooked : Dependency management.  Even with really good decoupled architecture there is still a level of dependencies between the separate elements and it  has to be managed.  Thing is this sort of management has now reached a good level of maturity with monolithic applications...

Comment: But since most microservice applications are deployed as though each services are independent applications themselves the dependency management tooling must now be taken from the build phase and ported directly in the runtime, it must become an actual part of your architecture or risk having an ever expanding array of services see your maintenance cost explode and your services stability degrade.  Seeing the combinatory aspects inherent to the service interactions this relation is not linear but more likely exponential... or if not kept in check...  god forbid factorial.

Comment: In conclusion, my point was that the more I read about different foray and experiments in the realm of microservices the more I read about them (re) discovering what in the 90's we called DLL hell with COM and DCOM and later jar hell with Java.  this problem was only really kept in check with the advent of Maven, OSGi or other similar dependency management systems before we could rise above and step on the next level of system complexity.

Comment: that said as dependency management is the bane of microservice and the strength of monolithic scalability plays in the opposite.  Microservice are inherently scalable and the tooling in exist to make this relatively easy.  In monolithic scalability has to be baked in the application in similar ways that dependency do with microservices.

Comment: Well in my case there are different ways I can manage dependency(ies) one would be the use managed package and versioning(nuget, npm, etc..). The thing I am wondering is making a domain model a dependency on all microservices, or use mapping on class data exchange. The associated cost of casting and boxing can often be proved to be high but on the other hand the basic principle of MS would be breached by having dependencies

Comment: @Newtopian had awesome points. Let me add my own two cents, microservices are mostly for dealing with political problems, not tech problems.

Comment: The political problems are real, though, as different business units, departments, and work groups have each their own responsibilities to meet, and services help them address that.  See also [Conway's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law): the observation that software design generally reflects org structure.

Answer (score 7):

Microservices have a very nice connection to DDD: in a sensible architecture, every microservice will handle a *single* bounded context.

Every bounded context has its own problem domain and therefore its own model. Instead of *sharing* parts of the model, keep the model nicely decoupled and *translate* between models. For microservices, the context boundary corresponds to the input/output of the microservice. You gain nothing by creating a model-microservice or sharing a common model-DLL because no common model exists. A client might be a “user account” in a user service context and a “credit card + billing address” in a payment service context. Just because they are somehow connected does not mean that you should represent them via a single entity in all contexts.

But speaking in practical terms, it can make sense to share a DLL that contains the DTOs and their serialization/deserialization. These DTOs do not represent the model of any context, but only the communication between your microservices. A shared library makes sure that serialization is always done correctly by avoiding repeated code, and it lets your services consume a strongly typed interface. The downside is this reduces one major benefit of microservices: technology-agnosticism. A common library also implies that deployments of new versions need to be synchronized.

Comment: And them your devs will put a bullet to their skulls after a while managing a few dozens different names for the same type of real-life thing. The beautiful thing of a shared model is to organize the _mind_ of the developer and keep how things interlock fresh on your mind. Have one model for each service, and you end up with a thousand mini-systems to manage, all of them completely different and needing a different mindset to work on. This isn't productive _at all_.

Comment: @T.Sar I don't disagree with you – microservices can be utter hell for exactly the reasons you describe. But distributing a shared model over multiple services can be problematic as well because now it's not clear where the boundaries between the services are. DDD is very insistent on finding clear context boundaries. In the end, distributing your complexity between countless small modules or few gigantic modules is both terrible design. The art of software architecture is about finding that perfect balance somewhere in between, with well-chosen, appropriate abstractions.

Comment: I find this a very good answer. As for technology-agnosticism: You don't lose that. Any consuming service can still connect _without_ using the shared DTOs. It's just that for those consumers that use the same technology, they can take a shortcut by using the same DTOs, with all the benefits that you describe. As for deployments of new versions needing to be synchronized, this can be mitigated by limiting how contracts may change. Optional additions are always fine. Anything else should result in a completely new, separate version, to avoid breaking changes.

Answer (score 2):

Put your Data Transfer Models in a shared library. Version it

Each service has to deserialise the incoming messages and serialise the out going ones. So really these shared models are only acting as a contract enforcement between your services and there is no point adding business logic to them.

However, for each microservice that you consume you will have to write a client library (ie a library that you use to connect to the service as apposed to a Client Model)

If this library uses the same shared models that all your services are using, it saves you a whole layer of mapping and conversion on every single component you use it in.

That's a lot of typing.

Also, the versioning will give you compile time warnings if you have the wrong model version for the client version.

Microservices by their nature push you towards an ADM style of programming which doesn't always fit with DDD unless you call the services themselves a Domain object. ie the CashRegisterService processes a payment rather than the Payment is processed

Comment: `Microservices by their nature push you towards an ADM style of programming`. It's totally false. The only that push us towards ADM is the lack on modelling skills. And that has nothing to do with Microservices.

Comment: its totally true, and a good thing too!

Answer (score 2):

Shared libraries generate coupling. That's it. Also does [canonical models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_model).

From the Microservices architectecture (*dogmatic*) point of view, any factor that may lead to coupling (direct or indirectly) among services is an undesirable factor, because it's contrary to the Microservice absolute independency.

Having two identical POJOs/entities in different Microservices is not a DRY violation.

Usually, Microservices are developed, managed and governed by different teams. Teams formed around business capabilities and skills (not otherwise).

In consequence, teams could not be allocated in the same department. Maybe, not even in the same building or city.

**Maybe, the Microservices don't even share the same technological stack.**

The problem here is a decomposition problem. It might interest you [this reading](https://builttoadapt.io/whats-your-decomposition-strategy-e19b8e72ac8f).

Whether we approach the decomposition from a *Boundary Contexts* or *Value stream* strategy, the definition of the model varies (or difers) according to the services, because every service is a business unit per se. It has his own domain, rules and logic.

So, *Customer*, *Order*, *Address*, etc have different definitions, according to the scope (service) from they are looked at.

For instance, from the security point of view a customer is not a customer at all. It's probably an account (credentials, roles, profiles, etc.)

From the Shipping Dept. point of view, a customer is a full name, an address and, maybe, a phone.

From the Sales Dept. point of view, a customer is a document id, a credit card and a full name.

It's fine having the attribute *name* and *address* in different Microservices' data models. Even if they are not synchronized!!!

In the real world, when we change the current billing address, the previous bills don't change!!! Or they should not! Same happens with prices. Or with names.

If several Microservices need to communicate changes on the state of the data, they don't directly communicate the changes, they propagate events that could (or not) be attended by others Microservices.

In Microservices, the SRP and DRY work in higher levels of abstraction (business and company's strategies)  than those we are more familiar with (classes and components).

Back to the main question, my answer is try to avoid shared libs. The main sources of coupling use to be inter-process synchronous communications and shared libraries. So, I encourage you to delve deeper in:  Microservices decomposition and Microservices inter-process communication strategies.